# NoClassDefFoundError when creating instance of Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have imported facebooksdk.jar in "Referenced libraries" section of Eclipse project. When an instance of Facebook is created, am running into the below exception. Facebook SDK is 3.15.0.

Any pointers to resolve the below is appreciated.

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NoClassDefFoundError))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
WebDialog.onCreate(Bundle) line: 208    
WebDialog(Dialog).dispatchOnCreate(Bundle) line: 361    
WebDialog(Dialog).show() line: 262  
AuthorizationClient$WebViewAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient$AuthorizationRequest) line: 628 
AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler() line: 264   
AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler() line: 230  
AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient$AuthorizationRequest) line: 154   
AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient$AuthorizationRequest) line: 135 
Session.tryLegacyAuth(Session$AuthorizationRequest) line: 1450  
Session.authorize(Session$AuthorizationRequest) line: 1165  
Session.open(Session$OpenRequest, SessionAuthorizationType) line: 1234  
Session.openForPublish(Session$OpenRequest) line: 503   
Facebook.openSession(Session, Session$OpenRequest, boolean) line: 319   
Facebook.authorize(Activity, String[], int, SessionLoginBehavior, Facebook$DialogListener) line: 313    
Facebook.authorize(Activity, String[], Facebook$DialogListener) line: 149   
FacebookConnector.login() line: 49  
AndroidFacebook.postMessage() line: 116 
AndroidFacebook.onCreate(Bundle) line: 57   
AndroidFacebook(Activity).performCreate(Bundle) line: 5231  
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1087   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2159    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2245 
ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 135    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1196  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 102    
Looper.loop() line: 136 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5017    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 779  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 595 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

After proceeding to run with the above breakpoint, another exception "InvocationTargetException" is observed with cause being "NoClassDefFoundError".

cause/target in Eclipse Variables window is as below
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$string

The entry in R.txt when facebook SDK jar was generated is not being found.

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070011, where the ID resolves to the below

int string com_facebook_loading 0x7f070011

Also have the below jar files included - android-support-v4, bolts.jar, android-support-v7-appcompat,appcompat_v7

Comment: This seems not to be the real stacktrace. Is it a copy auf the debugger tree? What goes to the console?

Comment: Rather occurs during facebook login and authorize flow.

Comment: @Hank, yes it is a copy of Debug window in Eclipse. The Thread is suspended due to exception NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Console does not seem to be showing anything useful. Using an emulator and last statement on console is "Attempting to connect debugger" that was printed prior to the run.

Comment: What if you catch the exception in your code and show it? Have you incluede the jars the sdk comes with?

Comment: Looks like my application is not able to access the resources in the generated facebook sdk jar file.

Comment: @Hank, exception is "InvocationTargetException" with output as ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$string

Comment: I found this too. line 208 https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java